# How to redirect // in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5

Older version of laravel here, 5.7.  I have a situation where I have a url like this http://127.0.0.1:8000//

I have a catch all of this

```php
Route::get('{uri}', ['uses'=>'PageController@render'])->where('uri', '(.*)');
```

The URL that comes into the `render` method is `''`.
I'm not quite sure the best way to take http://127.0.0.1:8000// and redirect that to http://127.0.0.1:8000.

.htaccess doesn't seem to let me redirect that either with
`Redirect 301 // /` or `RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]`

Is there any way to get around this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are treated as the same resource in the browser. Anyway you can check the **request URI** on the server and redirect to the root path like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    // check the request URI
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/')
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    # The rest of the code
    # ...
});
```

Comment: thanks @milad.  I have to faceplam for a bit, i thought i had tried that, but infact i was using `$_REQUEST['REQUEST_URI']` no wonder it didn't work for me :/

Comment: It happens to everyone. Glad it helped :)